# Binary search tree help insert function

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

My insert function compiles fine but if I try to add a 4th node it just replaces one of the first child nodes instead of adding a new one to those child nodes.

```
 bool bst::insert(string StudentName, int IDNumber) {

 class node *temp = root;
 class node *n=new node (StudentName, IDNumber);

    if (root==NULL) {
        root = n;
        return true;
    }
    if (temp -> ID == n->ID)
        return false;

    while (temp) {
        if (n-> ID < temp-> ID)
        { temp -> left = n;
            temp -> left -> parent= temp;
            temp = temp -> left;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->right=n;
            temp -> right ->parent=temp;
            temp = temp -> right;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is inside the `while` loop. The loop will only run once, because you always `return`, in both cases. So, you only can add 3 nodes (or less, depending on the values), and you never actually check if a node already exists.

To fix this, you have to change your code to do the following:

```
while (temp) {
    if (n-> ID < temp-> ID)
    {
        if(temp->left)
            temp = temp->left
        else
        {
            temp -> left = n;
            temp -> left -> parent= temp;
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
       // Analogously as for left
    }
}
return false; // This should never happen, but we have to return...
```

And I gotta admit, finding an answer [wasn't hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion)

Comment: i really appreciate it man... i just couldnt figure out that one line of temp -> left -> parent = temp i kept writing different things but never got it right. thanks a buddy!